# How to create data grid table using react-bootstrap and filtering, sorting options in data-grid

Tags: react-bootstrap-table

Example:
Table poped in Modal
There is a existing functionality in java application when we click on search button, It will pop up a modal window(like data table grid) and shows data in table format with filtering and sorting options, when we select the record from table it will be selected in existing form. How to achieve this using ReactJs and react-bootstrap ? any library to import and work on this requirement ?
Filtering, Sorting dropdowns...

Col1  Col2 Col3   +ADD row
---   ---- ----

When selected the row.. 
Col1 Col2 Col3    -Del row

Ok. When selected the row, the values will shown in main form

Answer (score 0):

I think the two main competitors here are:

[ReactDataGrid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/), also known as react-data-grid and https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

At least in the case of react-data-grid, it supports the features you are asking for, but there is work to get it integrated.  It provides UI to allow users to request sorting and filtering, but you have to actually sort and filter the data in response to the event.  It supports UI to allow in-place editing, and you can add rows dynamically, but you have to add buttons on the UI and respond to them in the appropriate way.

In react, getting a selection from a Modal dialog back to a detailed form view of an Object would normally happen through a store like [redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Getting all of this up and running from scratch is not a trivial task and would take a few days at least.